# Adjust UITextField with iPad split/moved keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm currently implementing in my app functionality that my `UITextField` would not be covered by the keyboard (when edited). It is pretty straight forward with the **keyboard notification methods** :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(p_keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(p_keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

But the problem with this is that they do not launch when the keyboard is in a different place (for example top) or split.

Any advice how to handle these situations?

Comment: You don't need to handle it. The _user_ is free to move the keyboard in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great article Working With Keyboard on iOS: http://macoscope.com/blog/working-with-keyboard-on-ios/

Comment: Thanks!  That was just the thing I was looking for.